# How to create subplots with little vertical spacing in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to do a figure in Matlab consisting of a grid of images (subplots). I have used the [subaxis](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot) toolbox:

```
subaxis(4,6,1, 'Spacing', 0.03, 'Padding', 0, 'Margin', 0);
```

The problem is that the vertical space between the subplots (images) is too big.

How can this be solved? The horizontal spacing is ok but I want the vertical spacing the same as the horizontal spacing. With the above toolbox this seems not working.

Comment: Looking at the help embedded in the `subaxis` header there is a `SpacingVert` property for this function. Have you tried using it?

Comment: @excaza Yes I have, it does not work. There are other comments to this toolbox saying that vertical spacing does not work. So I need another solution than this toolbox.